# Optimizing SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, query-optimization

I am trying to run a sql query that is taking a lot of time on mysql. The table is very big (over 160000 rows). I have below table structure

```
id | clientID | type | price | code | created_at
```

Desired output is:

```
ldate | Cid | Total | Total2
```

I am currently using this query:

```
select max(created_at) as ldate, clientID as Cid, 
  (SELECT SUM(price) as total from invoice 
   where clientID = Cid and type = 9  and code <> 0) as total,
  (SELECT SUM(price) as total from invoice 
   where clientID = Cid and type = 9 ) as total2 
from invoice 
group by clientID 
having max(created_at) < '2019-09-01'
```

Is there a way to optimize this query to run faster or is the issue only related to the large number of rows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Go read some of the many questions here on query optimization. Pay particular attention to those which have been upvoted and answered. Compare the information presented in the questions with those which are downvoted / unanswered / closed. Compare them with what you have presented here. There is a lot missing from your question.

Comment: Please defined what "run faster" means to you? this particular query runs in how much time? how much faster you want it? 160 000 rows isn't a big table, compare to tables in a data warehouse.

Comment: Please put aliases on each column reference; it is hard to keep track of which column is in which instance of `invoice`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand the intent of your query, you could use conditional aggregation rather than scalar subqueries, so the table is scanned only once:

```
select 
    max(created_at) as ldate, 
    clientid as cid, 
    sum(case when type = 9 and code <> 0 then price else 0 end) as total,
    sum(case when type = 9 then price else 0 end) as total2
from invoice 
group by clientid 
having max(created_at) < '2019-09-01'
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for